# Get the html source of a rendered ejs as string

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I have this piece of code inside a controller:

```
exports.getintroDetails = async (req, res) => {
    try {
      const details = await IntroModel.find();
      return res.render("final", { details , user:req.user });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error.message);
    }
};
```

This code, as expected, renders the final.ejs file with the given data.

But instead, I want to show raw html which we get after rendering final.ejs with the given data. Is there any way to store the raw html as a string instead of rendering it?

So, instead of:

```
return res.render("final", { details , user:req.user });
```

I want something like this:

```
return res.send( view-source( res.render("final", { details , user:req.user }) ) );
```

Is there any function like `view-source()` as described above?

Comment: Ehm, just read the question again.. Do you want to have the raw html?? Or the html before being sent? For having the raw html you can to read the template file using `fs`. ..

Comment: @SilvanBregy I mean, the html before being sent...

Comment: Good, that's in my answer ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [docs](http://expressjs.com/de/api.html#res.render) you can provide a `callback` which will be executed with the rendered `html`. When the callback is provided the response won't automatically be made.

```
exports.getintroDetails = async (req, res) => {
    try {
      const details = await IntroModel.find();
      return res.render("final", { details , user:req.user }, (err, html) => {

        console.log('rendered html!', html)

        // now, the response has to be made manually.
        res.status(200).send(html)
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error.message);
    }
};
```

It is also possible, to render it using `app.render()` for only receiving the `html`.

From the [docs](http://expressjs.com/de/api.html#app.render)

> Think of app.render() as a utility function for generating rendered view strings. Internally res.render() uses app.render() to render views.

```
app.render('final', function (err, html) {
  // ...
})
```

Comment: `html` is undefined.

Comment: and `err` ?? . i just tested `res.render()` locally and it worked. I used `"express": "4.16.x",`